# Corrupt zip file kills my PHP script

Tags: php, exec, unzip

I use `exec("unzip")` to unzip files on my server.

The problem is with corrupt file.

It kills my script instead of continue it, so I can't see the last sentence.

```
$dir_nom = '/root/';
$dir = opendir($dir_nom) or die('Error'); 
$fichier = "";
$dossier = "";
while($element = readdir($dir)) {
    if($element != '.' && $element != '..') {
        if (!is_dir($dir_nom.$element)) {$fichier[] = $element;}
        else {$dossier[] = $element;}
    }
}
closedir($dir);
foreach ($fichier AS $f) {
$start_f=substr($f, 0, 4);
if ($start_f=="ZIP_") {
    echo $f."\n";
    $namezip=exec("unzip /root/".$f."");
    unlink("/root/".$f);
}
}
echo "Everything is good";
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the question?

Comment: The error is corrupt zip, but it does not matter, i don't want my script to be kill by the error

Comment: Use a `try/catch` block

Comment: The error does matter. What exception do you get? You can catch that exception specifically in a try/catch block. That way your script won't exit and you can decide how to react to the exception.